# Does Android XWalkView have a process pool similar to WKProcessPool on iOS?

Tags: android, adfs, adfs2.0, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

Our hybrid application uses our corporate Google accounts for sign in. That in-turn uses Active Directory Foundation Services to authenticate our corporate accounts. Everything works nicely until sign-out. The ADFS server holds the user credentials in a cookie or session on the server. In iOS, I can completely invalidate everything by re-creating the WKWebView and providing it with a new fresh WKProcessPool, which then requires the user to re-sign in (required for shared devices)...

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let pool = WKProcessPool()
config.processPool = pool
let webView - WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, configuration: config)
```

Is there anything equivalent to that with XWalkView on Android? I am currently programmatically removing the old XWalkView and adding a new XWalkView to the main view when a logout occurs, calling clearCache, and using the cookie manager to remove all cookies, but I'm still logged into the ADFS server.

```
// Remove old xWalkView if it exists
if(xWalkView != null){
    ((ViewGroup) xWalkView.parent()).removeView(xWalkView);
    xWalkView.onDestroy();
    xWalkView = null;
}
// Create a new xWalkView
xWalkView = new xWalkView(this, this);
xWalkView.clearCache(true);
XWalkCookieManager cookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.flushCookieStore();
// Add to the main view
RelativeLayout layout = (RelaviteLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);
layout.addView(xWalkView, 0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.